# Adding levels in atomic vector in R (without using factor() function)

Tags: r

I am reading Hadley's Advanced R and was experimenting with `levels`. He says that when factors are properly created, one shouldn't be able to add incorrect factor to a vector. I accidentally created levels of an atomic vector, and `nlevels()` does indicate proper number of levels, but I am able to add a factor.

Here's my code:

```
y<- c(1:5,"a","b")
levels(y)<- c("1","2","3")
nlevels(y) #The output is 3
```

Now, let's check `y` again:

```
`y`
"1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "a" "b"
attr(,"levels")
"1" "2" "3"
```

We note that `y` is not a factor above.

However, now when I create a factor using `factor()`, I see traditional factor variable:

```
z<-factor(c(1:5,"a","b"))
```

I get five factors. Furthermore, when I try to add another element that is not a factor, it works well for `y` but not for `z`:

```
z[8] <- -1 #generates NA (as expected)
y[8]<-1 #This gets added.
```

Now, when I run class() command,

```
class(z) #it shows factor
class(y) #it shows atomic vector
```

Now, my confusion is that what happens when I create levels for a non-factor variable? Why is that I am able to add levels to it? `nlevels()` also returns correct number of factors. I'd appreciate any thoughts. I searched for SO and couldn't find an explanation on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your premise. There is a '1'- level for 'z"m so there is no NA created:

```
> z<-factor(c(1:5,"a","b"))
> z
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 a b
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 a b


> nlevels(z)
[1] 7
```

Creating a `levels` attribute is just like attaching any other attribute to a vector. You could define an `add_any_old_attribute` function that would take an attribute name and a vector of values and it would just be there if anyone found a use for it. Except that's just what the `attr<-`-function does. The `levels<-` is just a specialized version of the `attr<-` function.

Comment: - Thanks for your help, but why is it that `nlevels(y)` works (as in I see 3 levels created for `y`), and I am able to add a number that is not a level in `y`? I am still unclear

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Your `y`-object is not a factor. If you do: `y <- factor(y)` you will have 7 levels. The `factor`-function does more error checking than `levels`.

Comment: Exactly. The behavior you have described is what Hadley also talks about. I'd have expected `levels()` to prevent allowing us from adding a number to the vector `y` that is not specified in the `levels`. I agree that `y` object is not a factor, but it does behave like a factor when I call `str(y)` and `nlevels()`

Comment: Nope. unless I do y <- factor(y), `str` reports that Y is an atomic vector. `nlevels` just looks at the levels attribute. You could argue that `levels<-` should not be able to modify vectors, but I'm not sure how far you would get on the `r-devel` mailing list.